# Passing a Field for Access Query to a Module Function as an Array

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to write a function in a module that we take a field from a MS ACCESS query that is passed to it and return the values of the field to another field in the Query.

The code that I have written in the module is provided below.

```
    Public Function YearAmps(ByRef array1() As Double)

    Dim array2(0 To UBound(array1())) As Double

    Dim I

    For I = 0 To UBound(array2())
        array2(I) = array1(I)

    Next I

    YearAmps = array2

End Function
```

When I put the following in the Query field: YearAmps([SN]), where YearAmps is the function that I am calling and SN is the field that I am passing to the function and run the code, I get an error.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong. Is is possible to pass a field from an Query as an array in a Module and then return that array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you want, but array1 would be just a value of double not an array.  Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is this about a multi-valued field?